# Can anyone help me identify this No. 5 corrugated plane

Tags: plane, tool-identification

This No. 5 plane has no identifying marks other than No. 5 on the toe.  It has a corrugated bottom.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. Is this the only photo available??? Even were it much larger (*much*) this would possibly be an impossible ID problem because it's from just this one angle. Generally you'd want photos from various angles to see specific details. Even with that though, there's often no way to identify a plane definitively as having been made by one company although in this case it is possible the style of the corrugations might allow for some definitive rule-in/rule-out determinations.

Comment: Two key things to bear in mind for the future re. IDing a plane. 1, once Stanley's patents ran out copies aplenty appeared from makers all over the world, including Canada, Australia and Britain. And these were frequently *direct* copies, down to the oddball threading Stanley chose to use initially even though some were now obsolete/obscure. And 2, planes that follow the Bailey pattern can often have parts exchanged between them (because of 1). So a plane might possibly have been assembled from parts made by different makers, resulting in what's know colloquially as a Frankenplane.